# Error while using the weights option in nlme in r

Tags: r, mixed-models, weighted, nlme

Sorry this is crossposting from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593717/nlme-regression-with-weights-syntax-in-r, but I thought it might be more appropriate to post it here.

I am trying to fit a power curve to model some observations in an `nlme`. However, I know some observations to be less reliable than others (reliability of each `OBSID` reflected in the `WEIV` in the dummy data), relatively independent of variance, and I quantified this beforehand and wish to include it as weights in my model. Moreover, I know a part of my variance is correlated with my independent variable so I cannot use directly the variance as weights.

This is my model:

```r
coeffs_start = lm(log(DEPV)~log(INDV), filter(testdummy10,DEPV!=0))$coefficients

nlme_fit <- nlme(DEPV ~ a*INDV^b, 
                      data = testdummy10,
                      fixed=a+b~ 1, 
                      random = a~ 1, 
                      groups = ~ PARTID, 
                      start = c(a=exp(coeffs_start[1]), b=coeffs_start[2]),
                      verbose = F,
                      method="REML",
                      weights=varFixed(~WEIV))
```

This is some sample dummy data (I know it is not a great fit but it's fake data anyway) : https://github.com/FlorianLeprevost/dummydata/blob/main/testdummy10.csv

This runs well without the "weights" argument, but when I add it I get this error and I am not sure why because I believe it is the correct syntax:

```r
Error in recalc.varFunc(object[[i]], conLin) : 
dims [product 52] do not match the length of object [220]
In addition: Warning message:
In conLin$Xy * varWeights(object) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a [very](http://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/228411.html) [long-standing](https://web.archive.org/web/20041228001508/https://www.biostat.wustl.edu/archives/html/s-news/2004-03/msg00094.html) [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17712) in `nlme`. I have a patched version on Github, which you can install via `remotes::install_github()` as below ...

```r
remotes::install_github("bbolker/nlme")
testdummy10 <- read.csv("testdummy10.csv") |> subset(DEPV>0 & INDV>0)
coeffs_start <- coef(lm(log(DEPV)~log(INDV), testdummy10))
library(nlme)
nlme_fit <- nlme(DEPV ~ a*INDV^b, 
                      data = testdummy10,
                      fixed=a+b~ 1, 
                      random = a~ 1, 
                      groups = ~ PARTID, 
                      start = c(a=exp(coeffs_start[1]),
                                b=coeffs_start[2]),
                      verbose = FALSE,
                      method="REML",
                      weights=varFixed(~WEIV))
packageVersion("nlme") ## 3.1.160.9000
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, I still have an issue installing it, but I think I will try to uninstall lme4 & lmertest to see if it works!